# Enforcing AWS Glue table properties order

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm using boto3 to update a glue table's table parameters.
I'm doing this with the method update_table.

However, whatever order I push the TableInput parameter in, it gets ignored.

For example I push the following dict:

```
...
     "Parameters":  {
        "AVTOR":  "",
         "PROJEKT":  "",
         "PODROCJE":  "",
         "CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion":  "1.0",
         "CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion":  "1.0",
...
```

After updating the table, the table properties are in a random order:
[image]

Is there a way to enforce the table properties order with update_table?

Comment: I reckon you need to pass the required column orders in the `TableInput` section of the `update_table` function

Comment: @Amir Maleki Thats the problem. The order I have in `TableInput` gets ignored and the inserted order is random (like in the picture).